# Serialize a variable format field, one of two potential types

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am making a api request where one field can have to potential structures:

- a string (example: `"key": "24789223"`)
- an object (example: `"key": { value: "12121", "currency": "USD" }`)

I have tried to use an enum like this:

```
pub enum CustomAmount {
    ComplexAmount(ComplexAmount),
    SimpleAmount(String)
}
```

Where `ComplexAmount` is:

```
pub struct ComplexAmount {
    pub value: String,
    pub currency: String
}
```

However, when I try to deserialize from the json response I get the following error:

```
unknown variant `24789223 `, expected `CustomAmount` or `SimpleAmount`
```

I am using `wasm-bindgen`.

Is there a better way to allow a field to have two potential types?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to distinguish between two enum values (where there's not any extra info in the json like `"__type": "ComplexAmount"`), you need to add the `#[serde(untagged)]` macro to the enum declaration.

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum CustomAmount {
    ComplexAmount(ComplexAmount),
    SimpleAmount(String)
}
```

also make sure you've used `#[derive(Deserialize)]` on `ComplexAmount` as well.